# how to validate xml via xsd in java depending on value of an xml element

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

I am using Jaxb2Marshaller and using ValidationEventHandler-handleEvent(). i am storing any error message occurred in the process in a map. I am using xsd to validate mandatory/optional tags. So the problem is depending on the value of a tag in xml some other tags value can become mandatory/optional.

Now for all cases I have made separate xsd which try to check for respective mandatory fields. but how can i tell to jaxb that to validate the xml which xsd should be used?

```
<bean id="jaxb2MarshallerForABC" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="contextPath">
            <util:constant
                static-field="com.abc.pqr.util.ABCMessageConstants.PACKAGE_DATAMODEL_AB_IN_OB" />
        </property>
        <property name="schemas">
            <value>
                classpath:xsd/tc/oa/in/InboundMessageIss.xsd <!--Depending on xml value validate with different xsd/since there could be diffent tag as mandatory/optional -->
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="unmarshallerListener" ref="unMarshallingListenerForOA"/>
        <property name="validationEventHandler" ref="validationEventHandler" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that?:

```
<bean id="contractUnmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>Class1</value>
            <value>Class2</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="schemas">
        <list>
            <value>Class1Schema</value>
            <value>Class2Schema</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```